# Beautiful soup returning duplicates and skipping tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im trying to run a query to scrape names of restaurants from yelp, used selector gadget for getting the css. It returns 10 variables per page for 24 pages as expected, but 20% are duplicates so it doesnt return all desired tags.

```
# Getting the restaurant list for Boston, MA
import requests
url = "https://www.yelp.com/search?cflt=nightlife&find_loc=Philadelphia%2C+PA%2C+United+States&start=0"
html = requests.get(url)
html.content[0:500]

# Making the soup
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, 'lxml')

# Identifying the restaurant links
links = soup.select(".css-1egxyvc .css-1m051bw")
print(links[0:10])

# Getting the restaurant names and the restaurant links in isolation
name_restaurant = []
link_restaurant = []



for link in links:
    name_restaurant.append(link.string)
    link_restaurant.append(link.get('href'))
    

print(name_restaurant[0:5])
print(link_restaurant[0:5])

# Getting everything also for multiple pages (here, for page 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6)
url_yelp = 'https://www.yelp.com/search?cflt=restaurants&find_loc=Boston%2C%20MA&start='

for j in range(1,30):
    
    html = requests.get(url_yelp + str(j*10))
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, 'lxml')
    links = soup.select(".css-1egxyvc .css-1m051bw")
   
  
   
    for link in links:
        name_restaurant.append(link.string)
        link_restaurant.append(link.get('href'))

# Making sure we have everything
print(name_restaurant)  
print(link_restaurant)

# Completing the restaurant links
link_restaurant=["https://www.yelp.com" + s for s in link_restaurant]
print(link_restaurant[0:5])
```

using spyder 5.1.5

Comment: to format code use ``` instead of '''

Comment: I think I saw similar question few months ago.

Comment: simpler `for j in range(1, 300, 10):` and later `str(j)`

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see what you really get from server. Maybe it sends duplicated values. Maybe it send more than 10 values and you use step 10 so finally you ask for the same values. You should check `len( links )` to see if you get only 10 values or more.